# pd.read_csv(parse_dates... [date_formatter=]) returns dtype 'object' not 'datetime64'

Tags: python, datetime, csv, pandas, date-formatting

My input CSV has two datetime columns *'Start Time', 'End Time'* in timestamp format.

I can parse the timestamp ok but I can't get the resulting columns to be **datetime64**?!

Regardless whether I do or don't use my custom date-formatter `mdb_to_datetime()` or comment it out.
They keep being 'np.object' which is a wrapper for 'np.string'. (This blows up date-arithmetic later on.)

Trying to kludge `cal['Start Time'].astype(np.datetime64)`on the resulting object(string) column after the read_csv also fails.

```
from datetime import datetime

def mdb_to_datetime(ts):
    """Convert Access MDB to datetime"""
    return datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')

cal = pd.read_csv('my.csv', header=0,
    usecols = ['Start Time','End Time','Summary'],
    parse_dates = ['Start Time','End Time'] )
    #, date_parser = mdb_to_datetime )

# my.csv looks like (uninteresting columns removed):
Start Time,End Time,Summary
"1209396600","1209429000","some event"
"1226163600","1226206800","another event"
```

---

ADDENDUM:
1) thanks to @merlin2011, this now seems to do what I need, but can anyone shorten this line?

```
def mdb_to_datetime(ts):
    return np.datetime64(datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))
```

2) Does anyone else consider it a docbug that the documentation doesn't tell you anywhere a custom date-formatter should return `np.datetime64`?

Comment: @merlin2011: `np.datetime64(mydatestring)` worked (please reinstate your deleted answer!), just now `mdb_to_datetime()` is half a mile long.

Comment: I put it back in. I was about to update because I had been installing pandas.

Comment: I deleted the second half, because the output values look incorrect. Will update again if I figure out why. :)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions:

2) A custom date-formatter does not have to return a `np.datetime64`, just the datetime-like is good (the docs say: 'converting string to datetime instance'). So the `datetime.datetime` was OK, and there is no need to convert it to a string.

1) That answers also number one, you can shorten it by leaving the `strftime` out:

```
def mdb_to_datetime(ts):
    return datetime.fromtimestamp(float(ts))
```

And you can also use pandas `to_datetime` function: `pd.to_datetime(ts, unit='s')`

Comment: 2) I mentioned why datetime is **not** good enough: because datetime arithmetic fails: `cal[(cal['Start Time']>=...) & ... ]`. I need datetime64. That's what I said.

Comment: No, but the values in your dataframe will be `datetime64`. The `date_parse` just does not need to return it.

Comment: 1) No, that fails for me. As I said each element of each of the two datetime columns in cal ended up as a list with N=5467 elements.

Comment: ^^ The series in my dateframe has type np.object. Hence datetime-arithmetic on the **series** fails (example above). I've been saying this is the reason the dtype needs to be datetime64.

Comment: And if you include a call to `float` as I edited it? What error does it give?

Comment: Casting to `float` works. But why is that necessary? It's insane!

Comment: Because `datetime.fromtimestamp` expects a float? (as the error message said)